# Ways to compose Spock specs other than inheritance

Tags: groovy, spock

I currently have several Spock specifications like this:

```
class BlahSpec extends SpecParent
...
class SpecParent extends Specification
```

This works great for setup, but I would like to be able to mix in different types of tests, rather than having to explode a class hierarchy of parent tests.

Is there a solution for this, similar to RSpec modules?

Comment: I'm guessing this would involve Traits... but a more concrete example would be necessary in order for someone to convert it.